# Why we needs an error handling class or functions?

Tags: php, error-handling

If we can handling the error with the help of control structures, why do we need the classes and functions used for error handling?

For example; I can write a code in PHP with error handling class like this;

```
<?php
    $number1=100;
    $number2=0;

    try {

    if ($number2==0){
    throw new Exception("In the division process, the divisor cannot be zero.", 1);
    }

    echo $number1/$number2;
    } catch (Exception $error) {
    echo $error->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

And this code's output is;

```
In the division process, the divisor cannot be zero.
```

So, I can write the same code as below even shorter:

```
<?php
    $number1=100;
    $number2=0;

    if ($number2==0){
    echo "In the division process, the divisor cannot be zero.";
    } else {
    echo $number1/$number2;
    }
?>
```

and the output of this code is the same as above:

```
In the division process, the divisor cannot be zero.
```

So, why do we need the classes and functions used for error handling?

Comment: Because one thing you can always count on is that the user will find some ingenious way to break things... ways that you never dreamed were possible

Answer (score 1):

Because if you have 100 lines of codes and you expect 25 lines/piece of codes among them to fail, you would need to write 25 if/else statements. With error handling, its just:

```
<?php
try
{
    //100 lines of codes
}
catch(\Exception $e)
{
    //echo $e->getMessage();
    //echo $e->getLine();
    var_dump($e->getTrace());
}
```

and fix accordingly.